# Why is include folder empty after make install using cmake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am trying to create a lib and include for my project so that others can use my project. 
So I have my project structured as

```
├── mlce
   ├── CMakeLists.txt
   ├── README.txt
   ├── include
   ├── lib
   └── src
       ├── io
       │   └── IO.h
       └── mesh
           ├── Mesh.cpp
           └── Mesh.h
```

Currenly include and lib are empty. I created them manually so that latter on when I `make install` those will get filled.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(mlcelib)

set (SOURCE
    ${SOURCE}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mesh/Mesh.cpp
)

set (HEADER
    ${HEADER}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mesh/Mesh.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/io/IO.h
)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen)
message(${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}) # <--- I was hoping
          # this  "PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}" would place all the header file of my project inside include folder. 
          # But apparently it is not doing that. The include folder is empty.
```

Then what I do is :

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/path/to/mlce/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=/path/to/mlce/include ..
make 
make install
```

So when I do make install only the lib is filled by the shared lib but the install is not.

```
├── include
├── lib
│   └── libmlcelib.dylib
```

I was expecting include would contain mesh/Mesh.h and IO/IO.h

Comment: adding `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADER}")` did the trick. It would be great if some one could explain why I had to add that.

Comment: how else would CMake know what headers to install?

Comment: @John I agree with you.